# SQL CleanUp Job to delete old backup files in shared folder

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I tried the following three ways to clean-up the old backup files but none of them is worked. We need your help on this to complete.

Way 1: Created  Maintenance Cleanup Job, the job successful executed  but backup was not deleted the files.

Way 2: Tried using `xp_delete_file` command.

Script Used:

```
EXECUTE master.sys.xp_delete_file 0,N'\\XXX\YYY',N'bak',N'2014-05-12T07:34:14'
```

Error Message:

> Executed as user: DOMAIN\user. The process could not be created for
>   step 3 of job 0x307C7663CBCA6D4187B1953745E1E02F (reason: The system
>   cannot find the file specified).  The step failed.

Way 3: Tried using the power shell script

Script Used:

```
$Path = "\\xxx\yyy"

$Daysback = "-30"

$CurrentDate = Get-Date

$DatetoDelete = $CurrentDate.AddDays($Daysback)

Get-ChildItem $Path -Recurse -include *.bak| Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt $DatetoDelete } |  remove-item -force
```

Error Message:

> Executed as user: DOMAIN\user.. The job script encountered the
>   following errors.
>
> These errors did not stop the script:  A job step received an error at
>   line 9 in a PowerShell script.
>
> The corresponding line is 'Get-ChildItem $Path -Recurse -include
>   *.txt, *.bak| Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt $DatetoDelete } |  remove-item -force'. Correct the script and reschedule the job. The
>   error information returned by PowerShell is: 'Cannot find path
>   '\xxx\yyy' because it does not exist.  '.  Process Exit Code 0.  The
>   step succeeded.

The Powershell script was executed successfully in powershell window but not in the powershall task. also i have created proxy account which user has permission over the shared path and used the poroxy account to run the tasks.

Please help me to solve the issue.

Comment: For Way 1, how do you give the path for the cleanup step? It does not work if you give network path like \\SharedPath. Map network path to local drive and change path to the local path. Try again

Comment: Any other way without mapping network path to local drive. Anything wrong in way 2 and 3

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure about Way 3. Way 2 also looks like the same issue. However you can backup/cleanup to the shared folder if the account under which the service is running, has network access. This blog may help
http://www.howtogeek.com/51788/how-to-backup-sql-databases-to-a-network-share/

Answer (score 0):

There needs to be a back slash at the end of the path name, so '\\XXX\YYY' needs to be '\\XXX\YYY\' (note the extra backslash) - so the command becomes:

```
EXECUTE master.sys.xp_delete_file 0,N'\\XXX\YYY\',N'bak',N'2014-05-12T07:34:14'
```